# automatically convert low-quality tracks when added to iTunes library

Tags: itunes

When I add new tracks to iTunes, some of them are too low-quality to add to iCloud.  I have to manually convert them to AAC.  How can I have iTunes automatically do this so all of my tracks can go straight to the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you should be able to go through these steps:

1. Choose Edit > Preferences, click General, and click Import Settings.
2. Choose AAC format from the Import Using pop-up menu.

In that same window, you can also choose other import settings that may be of interest to you.

Comment: That won't *automatically* convert newly added tracks. Thanks tho.

Comment: It will automatically when you do an import.  Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  What do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: so this will automatically convert tracks that are ripped from a CD.  most newer computers don't use those anymore.  when i download a file using safari it's automatically played in iTunes.  i can manually convert the file to AAC using the settings i specified in Import Settings.  However, I'd like it to automatically convert that file when it is added to my library.  thanks!